# How to map south button on gamepad to behave like the left mouse button?

Tags: unity, c#, input, gamepad

How would I tell Unity that the left mouse button is being pressed when I actually press the south button on a gamepad?

Comment: Which input handling are you using - the legacy Input Manager, or the new Input System Package? What outcome do you want this virtual mouse click to trigger? Some actions have shortcuts that make this very easy, but to show you that we need details of your use case, because the exact steps differ.